# Defining a QML structure that only holds functions

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to QT, and I've had difficulty finding resources on the internet, so I thought I'd try my luck here. I am trying to create a QML file that only contains functions (slots?) and import that file into my main application. The functions would specifically be related to handling phone calls (e.g. `placeCall`, `endCall`, `callDisconnected`, etc.). My first thought was to use create a "CallManager.qml" file and use the `Component` type like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQml 2.3

Component {
    function makeCall(number) { ... }
    function endCall() { ... }
    // etc.
}
```

Then, I would do the following in main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    Button {
        x: 0; y: 0
        text: "Call"
        onClicked: callManager.placeCall("1234567890")
    }
    CallManager {
        id: callManager
    }
}
```

I just want to know if this is a valid way to solve the problem or if there are better practices for achieving the same results.

Comment: If you want to group your functions you don't need qml file, use js instead. See more info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html). That's the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a javascript file ".JS" in your resources and then import it like you import any QML file and in this JS file just add your functions and call them from any other QML file

Comment: Hey, thank you! I was not aware that .js files could be used. This seems like the perfect solution!